# Can't open Localhost:1313 in windows 10

Tags: hugo

I followed the tutorial on the https://gohugo.io/overview/quickstart/ . I've been able to do up until step 5  that is using the hugo server command.
But, when I accessing localhost:1313 in browser, the browser (chrome and edge) didn't reach network.
I also try using 127.0.0.1:1313, but the browser didn't reach too. Hiw to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Does `hugo server` runs corectly?

Answer (score 2):

almost same here, couldn't figure out what was the problem - the browser reached the address but rendered just a blank page. I solved it by running hugo server with theme appendix, like:

```
hugo server --theme=your_theme_name
```

Be sure to change the theme name in the line above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, turned out it was because hugo can't find the theme. 
In my case, I was git cloning project that contains themes as git submodule, (then I got empty theme folder, and Need to to pull the submodule contents)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is your themes folder. Look under your themes folder and check that the  has code in it. If not then, just git clone your theme under themes folder. 
Ex - [javahabit.com](http://www.javahabit.com) is using `hugo-w3-simple` theme. If you look under git folder of
`javahabit.com/themes/hugo-w3-simple` and find that there is no code, then `hugo` will serve blank page. To resolve this just delete the empty folder `hugo-w3-simple` and clone the theme again under `javahabit.com/themes/` folder.

> `git clone https://github.com/jesselau76/hugo-w3-simple.git`

Start the server again and you should be able to see your site. 
I too faced the same issue as when I was pushing my code to git, my themes sub-folder folder were not pushed and as result, when I cloned my blog on another laptop, the themes code was missing.

Answer (score 0):

***Check if your theme folder is empty. if yes, follow the guide.***

If you have your theme as a  git submodule it won't be cloned by default.

use `--recursive` flag while `git clone`.

It will clone submodules as well.

```
git clone --recursive url_to_git_repo
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case
in `config.toml`  I change

```
baseURL = '/'
languageCode = 'en-uk'
title = 'My New Hugo Site'
theme = 'ananke'
```

and works fine.
But I think the different make
if you

```
echo theme = \"ananke\" >> config.toml
```

then you get

```
theme = "ananke"
```

and this make a problem replace `theme ="your_theme"` in to `theme ='your_theme'`.(double in to single quote).